# How to show the associativity in Kleisli category

Tags: category-theory

Let $\langle T,\eta, \mu\rangle$ be a monad over a category $C$.

I want to show the associativity in Kleisli category $C_T$.

Suppose that $f_T$ is an arrow in $C_T$ which correspond to $f: X \to T(Y)$ in $C$, and that $g_T \circ_T f_T$ is a composition in $C_T$ which correspond to $\mu_z \circ T(g) \circ f$ where $g: Y \to T(Z)$.

The associativity in $C_T$ is

$h_T \circ_T (g_T \circ_T f_T) = (h_T \circ_T g_T) \circ_T f_T$

where $f: X \to T(Y)$, $g: Y \to T(Z)$, and $h: Z \to T(W)$.

I think that bellow equastions are hold.

$h_T \circ_T (g_T \circ_T f_T) = \mu_W \circ T(h) \circ (\mu_Z \circ T(g) \circ f)$

$(h_T \circ_T g_T) \circ_T f_T = \mu_W \circ T(\mu_W \circ T(h) \circ g) \circ f = \mu_W \circ T(\mu_W) \circ T(T(h)) \circ T(g) \circ f$

So I want to show $T(h) \circ \mu_Z = T(\mu_W) \circ T(T(h))$, but for me it is difficult.

Comment: Use `\langle` and `\rangle`, not `<` and `>`. The spacing in the latter is wrong.

Comment: Hint: start from $(h_T \circ_T g_T) \circ_T f_T$ and apply the associativity and naturality of $\mu$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for correcting my question.

Comment: @SCappella Thank you. I could show the associativity by your hint !

Comment: $(h_T \circ_T g_T) \circ_T f_T = \mu_W \circ T(\mu_W \circ T(h) \circ g) \circ f = \mu_W \circ T(\mu_W) \circ TT(h) \circ T(g) \circ f$. Using the associativity of $\mu$ i.e. $\mu_W \circ T(\mu_W) = \mu_W \circ \mu_{T(W)}$ this is equal to $\mu_W \circ \mu_{T(W)} \circ TT(h) \circ T(g) \circ f$. Using the natulality of $\mu$ i.e. $\mu_{T(W)} \circ TT(h) = T(h) \circ \mu_Z$ this is equal to $\mu_W \circ T(h) \circ \mu_Z \circ T(g) \circ f$. Finally this is equal to $h_T \circ_T (g_T \circ_T f_T)$.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can answer your own question and even accept the answer.